# Unable to enter the Uname&pwd in the Alert Popup in same page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I tried Using below code but not worked.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.sendKeys("Uname" + Keys.TAB + "pwd"); 
alert.accept();
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwHUU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Verify the popup present after the landing page loaded,if popup presents use `getcurrenturl` method and concatenate the username and password with the current url.

e.g., http://Username:Password@CurrentURL

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code it may work

```
driver.get('https://example.com/')
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("username" + Keys.TAB + "password");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: The above will work when the login is in basic url..but my authentication will come in after 1st page,the authentication url is dynamic based on search results